# PHP script timing out

Tags: php

I have a script that I would like to be able to run overnight to collect data. It goes through a loop then sleeps for 2.5 minutes, however after 18 iterations it always stops. I believe these lines are supposed to keep it from terminating:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
```

I have tried running the script in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Comment: Your webhost may disable those lines of code to prevent users from abusing the server

Comment: Just because the script will run forever doesn't mean your browser will remain connected forever. The connection itself will likely timeout.

Comment: I suggest running the script server side from php interpreter first, then with a web server.